# How to check if communication between two nodes on specific port is possible

Tags: ansible

I have two machines, there is a need to check that machine-1 must be able to communicate with machine-2 over port 10250 using TCP protocol, similarly machine-2 must be able to communicate with machine-1 over port 2380 using UDP protocol. For this I thought to use Ansible and write an Ansible script, but I am not sure how this can be achieved.
Please let me know your views.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Just for testing writing an ansible playbook is not a good idea as per me. But if you want to write, you can follow the below steps:

1. Create a file named "inventory" --> this file will host port no. and host name
2. Write a playbook that will perform the tasks.

Structure:

inventory

```
[UDP]
xx.xx.xx.xx

[UDP:vars]
port_number = 2380

[TCP]
xx.xx.xx.xx

[TCP:vars]
port_number = 10250
```

playbook

```
---
name: play to test the port connection
hosts: "{{ hosts }}"
tasks:
  - name: check if port is working.
    <module_name>: .......
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I have tried an ansible playbook for your requirement.

```
- hosts: host[1:2].xxx.xx
  gather_facts: False
  become: yes
  vars:
    host1: host1.xxx.xx
    host2: host2.xxx.xx

  tasks:
    - name: Check port from host1 to host2
      wait_for: host={{host2}} port=10250 timeout=1
      delegate_to: "{{host1}}"

    - name: Check port from host2 to host1
      wait_for: host={{host1}} port=2380 timeout=1
      delegate_to: "{{host2}}"
```